# Compute $\int_0^{+\infty} u^3 e^{-u(1+i)}du $

Tags: integration

Let $i^2=-1$. I want to compute the integral:
$$I=\int_0^{+\infty} u^3 e^{-u(1+i)}du .$$
My idea is to substitute variables with $v=(1+i)u$ and link to the Gamma function. But then the region goes from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to something in the complex plane.

Any advice ?

Comment: Did you mean to put $e^{-(1+i)u}$ in the integrand?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the minus.

Comment: The result should be $$\frac{-3}{2}$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, you have an extra minus sign there.

Comment: I is just corrected!

Comment: You could integrate by parts three times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-au}du= \frac 1a$$

and,

$$\int_0^{\infty} u^3 e^{-au}du = -\frac{d^3I(a)}{da^3}=\frac{6}{a^4}$$

Thus,

$$\int_0^{\infty} u^3 e^{-u(1+i)}du = \frac{6}{(1+i)^4}=-\frac32$$

Comment: Thanks alot ! it is exactly what I needed. Simple and elegant.

Comment: @anonymus - you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

Using your substitution we have,

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty u^3 e^{-(1+i)u}\,\mathrm du\\ 
 &= \frac{1}{(1+i)^4}\int_0^{(1+i)\infty}v^3 e^{-v}\,\mathrm dv,\qquad v=(1+i)u.\\ 
\end{align*}$$

Now we'd really like to evaluate the integral

$$J=\int_0^{(1+i)\infty}v^3 e^{-v}\,\mathrm dv.$$

We can go about doing this by considering the contour integral

$$\oint_{C_R} z^3 e^{-z}\,\mathrm dz$$

where $C_R$ is the following pizza-slice contour of radius $R$ in the 1st quadrant of the complex plane:

[image: 24]

Bounding the absolute value of the integral along the semicircular arc shows that it (the integral along the arc) goes to $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, then we find that

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\oint_{C_R} z^3 e^{-z}\,\mathrm dz=J+\int_\infty^0 x^3 e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

But since $z^3 e^{-z}$ is entire on the region enclosed by $C_R$ we have that, by Cauchy's integral theorem,

$$\begin{align*}
 0 &= J+\int_\infty^0 x^3 e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx \\ 
 &\Rightarrow J=\int_0^\infty x^3 e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx \\ 
 &= \Gamma(4) 
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{\Gamma(4)}{(1+i)^4}\\ 
 &= -\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What does $(1 + i)\infty$ mean?

Comment: @rubik, $(1+i)\infty$ is $(1+i)\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}R$. That doesn't seem like a satisfying answer though; what it means here geometrically is that it's the limit of the loction upper-most point on the diagonal line in the contour as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @dxdydz Thank you for your reply. I don't know much about complex integration but now I understand a bit more the need.